# Как внести текущую дату в несколько столбцов с помощью триггера?

Tags: sql, sql-server, дата, триггер

Имеется таблица примерно такого содержания:

```
  CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Actavia] (
        [Id]          INT           IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
        [НО]          NVARCHAR (50) NULL,
        [Дата НО]     DATE          NULL,
        [ВО]          NVARCHAR (50) NULL,
        [Дата ВО]     DATE          NULL,
    );
```

С помощью тригера при создании новой записи в  [Дата НО] вносится текущая дата

```
CREATE TRIGGER NumNOtrigger1
ON dbo.Actavia
AFTER INSERT
AS
UPDATE Actavia
SET 
    [Дата НО] = GETDATE() WHERE id=(SELECT id from inserted)    
GO
```

Суть вопроса. Как внести текущую дату в остальные столбцы, если на попытку сделать нижеуказанным способом ругается о неверном синтаксисе?

```
SET 
   [Дата НО] = GETDATE() WHERE id=(SELECT id from inserted),
   [Дата ВО] = GETDATE() WHERE id=(SELECT id from inserted)         
GO
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Доброго времени суток,sky_diez.

CREATE TRIGGER NumNOtrigger1
ON dbo.Actavia
AFTER INSERT
AS
UPDATE Actavia
SET  [Дата НО] = GETDATE(),
[Дата ВО] = GETDATE()
FROM Actavia X
JOIN inserted i ON X.id = i.id  
GO
```

Comment: И Вам доброго времени. Спасибо за помощь. Работает

Comment: Спасибо, рада помочь)

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте сделать так

```
CREATE TRIGGER NumNOtrigger1
ON dbo.Actavia
AFTER INSERT
AS
UPDATE Actavia
SET 
    [Дата НО] = GETDATE(),
    [Дата ВО] = GETDATE() 
WHERE id IN (SELECT id from inserted)        
GO
```

А лучше забыть про триггер и заполнить таблицу по другому

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Actavia] (
        [Id]          INT           IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
        [НО]          NVARCHAR (50) NULL,
        [Дата НО]     DATE          NOT NULL Default GetDate(),
        [ВО]          NVARCHAR (50) NULL,
        [Дата ВО]     DATE          not NULL default GetDate(),
    );
```

Comment: Благодарствую. Работает как надо!

Comment: Код ниже работать тоже будет. Просто я написал в вашем же стиле чтоб не создавать путаниц. Пользуйтесь

Comment: Академический вопрос: 
WHERE id IN (SELECT id from inserted) 
 будет распространятся на все условия которые я могу вставить после SET?

Comment: После set идут не условия вовсе а принимающая колонка и и значение которое оно принимает. А условия пишутся на соединениях либо после where. Отсюда следует set .... ColumnName = value,... Where (conditions)

Comment: И вообще триггеры вещь не явная, лучше воспользоваться constraint для поля в вашем случае.

Comment: Обычно триггеры используют для какого нибудь скрытого действия (добавления, изменения информации в других таблицах)